# Codeigniter can't read cookie set with Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, codeigniter, cookies

I am trying without success to read a cookie in codeigniter that has been set in the browser with Javascript.

The cookie is set in the browser as follows:

```js
// cookieContents is an array of integers
strForCookie = JSON.stringify(cookieContents);
date.setTime(date.getTime() + (2 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000)); // 2 days
$.cookie('savedPlaces', strForCookie, { expires: date });
```

I have checked in the browser that the cookie is set properly.

On the server I have the following codeigniter code in a controller:

```js
$this->load->helper('cookie');
$savedPlaces = $this->input->get_cookie('savedPlaces');
if ($savedPlaces == false) echo("Cookie doesn't exist!");
else echo("Cookie is: ".$savedPlaces);
```

The controller function is called by the following html:

```html
<a href="/browser/saved/">Saved searches</a>
```

I have never used cookies before so suspect I am doing something fundamentally wrong. Can anyone illuminate me?

Comment: Are you sure you do not have an already existing cookie with the same name? It sometimes give error when you set cookies with same names.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by an already existing cookie? The browser successfully writes the cookie 'savedPlaces', shouldn't the server be able to read this cookie? How can I create a cookie with the same name? Doesn't it just overwrite the cookie rather than creating a new one with the same name?

Comment: Well i had a similar problem and in the end i found that it was conflicting with CodeIgniters default cookie setter

Comment: Can you advise what I can do to ensure this isn't happening? I am not using codeigniter to set any cookies. These are set client side.

Comment: I am not sure about it - it has been long didnt touch CodeIgnitor so thought to share how i resolved issue. Hope someone else can help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `{path: '/'}` option to make the cookie available to your entire site or '{path: '/browser/saved/'}' to receive the cookie only on this controller function.

```
$.cookie('savedPlaces', strForCookie, {expires: date, path: '/'});
```

By default the cookie path is set to the current page's path and will only be available to that path.